# Android - what is the meaning of StableIDs?

Tags: android, listview

I'm implementing a ListAdapter of ExpandableListView, while working i see that i need to overide the function boolean hasStableIds().
Can anyone explain please what is the meaning of stable ids? when I need this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Stable IDs allow the `ListView` to optimize for the case when items remain the same between `notifyDataSetChanged` calls. The IDs it refers to are the ones returned from `getItemId`.

Without it, the `ListView` has to recreate all `View`s since it can't know if the item IDs are the same between data changes (e.g. if the ID is just the index in the data, it has to recreate everything). With it, it can refrain from recreating `View`s that kept their item IDs.

Comment: **e.g. if the ID is just the index in the data, it has to recreate everything** Shouldn't this be the opposite of the truth? I mean, if the id is just the index than it's always stable since it will never change. The element at index n will always return an id of n and so will never be changed. And my logic is supported by the explanation given by @DanyloVolokh

Comment: That's the case of you use hasStableIds with array indices returned from getItemId, yes. I admit, the wording isn't great. Edits welcome :)

Comment: And just to be clear, as per the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds()) it should return `true` when an `id` is guaranteed to refer to a particular unique object, such that a change in `id` signifies an object changed and an `id` remaining the same means it is not some new object returning the same `id` in which case the view would have to be updated and the method would be required to return `false`.

Comment: **Without it, the ListView has to recreate all Views**
On the contrary, Views are in a `RecycledViewPool` and should be recycled. To me the advantage of stable Ids is that you don't need to bind them again. Or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 21):

If `hasStableIds()` returns `false` then each time you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` your Adapter will look at the returned value of `getItemId` and will eventually call `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. If `hasStableIds()` returns `true` the this will only be done when their id has changed.

Using this technique you can easily update only one Item in the ListView

If you implement `getItemId`correctly then it might be very useful.

Example :

You have a list of albums :

```
class Album{
     String coverUrl;
     String title;
}
```

And you implement `getItemId` like this :

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    Album album = mListOfAlbums.get(position);
    return (album.coverUrl + album.title).hashCode();
}
```

Now your item id depends on the values of **coverUrl** and **title** fields and if you change them and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, then the adapter will call getItemId() method of each element and **update only those items which id has changed.**

This is very useful if are doing some "heavy" operations in your `getView()`.

Comment: I think, you meant "If hasStableIds() returns **true**", right?

Comment: No, I meant "false". When ids are not stable. (Mutable)

Comment: Regarding your example, what would happen if `hashCode()` returns the same number for 2 different strings (i.e. you have a hash codes collision)? And generalizing, if your `getItemId(int position)` returns not unique IDs. how it affects the `ListView`?

Comment: This way I assume you will have incorrect behavior. You should return unique id for unique items. Hash code is not ideal. But either way "long" is limited so we cannot guarantee the id to be absolutely unique.

Comment: **-1. This answer is completely wrong.** The RecyclerView can only avoid unnecessary work in this way when items have stable ids and you call setHasStableIds(**true**). The sample code will not work the way the writer says it does under any circumstances. hasStableIds() asks a question about item **identities**, not about item **values**. If hasStableIds() returns false, the adapter must recreate all views on every update, as it cannot assume list items with the same ID correspond to the same data.

Comment: In addition to @ClementCherlin 's comment, hashCode method is unreliable to use as identifier. Remember that hashes do not guarantee uniqueness, but rather inability to ***find*** a collision. Collision can be very common in hash functions and for large datasets, they could cause inconsistency between data provided and data displayed.

Comment: It looks like a simpler version of DiffUtils