# Android ListViews and Adapters

Tags: android, android-listview

This is going to be a very straight-forward question.

When you perform a 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, ListView refreshes all it's content, by reloading every single row.

I want to avoid this relayout, so I've read this answer([Android - what is the meaning of StableIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217416/android-what-is-the-meaning-of-stableids)):

> Stable IDs allow the ListView to optimize for the case when items remain the same between 
>   notifyDataSetChanged calls. The IDs it refers to are the ones returned
>   from getItemId.
>
> Without it, the ListView has to recreate all Views since it can't know
>   if the item IDs are the same between data changes (e.g. if the ID is
>   just the index in the data, it has to recreate everything). With it,
>   it can refrain from recreating Views that kept their item IDs.

So I overrode that method and returned `true`, then I managed to get a unique ID for every row. However, when I trigger `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` the listview recalculates everything.

The thing, is that I want to avoid this all recalculation, because the existing rows are not going to change, just several news are going to be added in the bottom (think about a pagination).

Is there any way to avoid full relayout of the ListView?

Thank you.