# Remembering which checkbox was checked with a search filter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-filter

Spent hours trying to get this to work but to no avail :(
I have set up a searchfilter for my listview, which works fine. But each has a checkbox - when I check the checkbox either before or after filtering, it is not being remembered which makes the filter pointless. Would appreciate some guidance here.

My code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private AllStuffModel[] modelItems = AllStuff.allConditions;
    private ListView conditionsView;
    private SearchView search_view;
    private AllStuffAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new AllStuffAdapter(this, new ArrayList<AllStuffModel>(Arrays.asList(modelItems)), this);
        conditionsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.condition_list);
        conditionsView.setAdapter(adapter);

        search_view = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

AllStuffAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AllStuffAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AllStuffModel> implements Filterable {
    private List<AllStuffModel> modelItems;
    private List<AllStuffModel> filteredModelItems;
    private Context context;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private ValueFilter valueFilter;

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public AllStuffAdapter(Context context, List<AllStuffModel> resource, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        super(context, R.layout.condition_row, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.modelItems = resource;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        filteredModelItems = modelItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.condition_row, parent, false);
        TextView conditionText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condition_text);
        final CheckBox conditionCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condition_checkbox);
        conditionCheckBox.setId(position);
        conditionText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!conditionCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    conditionCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(true);
                }
                else if(conditionCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    conditionCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                    modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(false);
                }
                System.out.println( modelItems.get(position).isChecked());
            }
        });


        conditionText.setText(modelItems.get(position).getName());
        conditionCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) v;
                if (currentCheckBox.isChecked()) { // If checked set to true, else false
                    modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(true);
                } else if (!currentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(false);
                }
                System.out.println( modelItems.get(position).isChecked());
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return modelItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<AllStuffModel> filterList = new ArrayList<AllStuffModel>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filteredModelItems.size(); i++) {
                    if ((filteredModelItems.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        AllStuffModel allConditionsModel = new AllStuffModel(filteredModelItems.get(i).getCode(),filteredModelItems.get(i).getName());

                        allConditionsModel.setIsChecked(filteredModelItems.get(i).isChecked());

                        filterList.add(allConditionsModel);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = filteredModelItems.size();
                results.values = filteredModelItems;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            modelItems = (ArrayList<AllStuffModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

AllStuffModel.java

```
    public class AllStuffModel {
        private String name;
        private String code;
        private boolean isChecked;


        public AllStuffModel(String code, String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
        }


        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public String getCode() {
            return this.code;
        }


        public boolean isChecked() {
            return isChecked;
        }


        public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked) {
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }

AllStuff.java

    public class AllStuff {

        private AllStuff() {

        }

        public static final AllStuffModel[] allConditions = {
                new AllStuffModel("ca", "Candy"),
                new AllStuffModel("fo", "Football"),
                new AllStuffModel("mu", "Music"),
                new AllStuffModel("sn", "Snooker"),
        };

    }
```

condition_row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/condition_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/condition_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#DE000000"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:queryHint="Search...." />




        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/condition_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>


    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

What I have tried to do is use `notifyDataSetChaanged()` in my onClick methods in `AllStuffAdapter`, but this stops the checkbox from being checked completely.

TL/DR: **How can I remember checkboxes checked with the search filter?**

Comment: I think it could be something to do with `hasStableIds` and your implementation of `getItemId` - You need a unique id, and `getItem(position)` is not a uniqueId between filtered datasets i.e. position '0' between filtered lists can be 2 totally different items, but the 'id' is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26206584/4252352 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217552/4252352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @faranjit, I believe adding this (with your changes) fully resolves the issues after `modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(isChecked);`. Could this be verified please?

```
for(AllStuffModel item: filteredModelItems){
                    if(modelItems.get(position).getCode().equals(item.getCode())){
                        item.setIsChecked(isChecked);
                    }
                }
```

We just update the list by matching the right item. Note: the `code` is something I set myself and I can always guarantee it will be unique.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
conditionCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) v;
            if (currentCheckBox.isChecked()) { // If checked set to true, else false
                modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(true);
            } else if (!currentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(false);
            }
            System.out.println( modelItems.get(position).isChecked());
        }
    });
```

to

```
conditionCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
conditionCheckBox.setChecked(modelItems.get(position).isChecked());
conditionCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            modelItems.get(position).setIsChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this - the original issue seems to be resolved. However, the issue that I have now, is that if I check something (when I've searched for something i.e. filtering), then return to the normal view, that check isn't stored.

Comment: Similarly, if (in the filtered view) I uncheck something that was checked normally, this change isn't reflected. I tried to use              `notifyDataSetChanged();` before returning my results, but this lead my app to crash. I suspect this is because I'm within the ValueFilter class and not AllStuffAdapter. TL/DR: If I make a change in the filtered view, it is not reflected in the actual normal view

Comment: In `getView` you use `modelItems` for filter you use `filteredModelItems` and only constructor of adapter has assignment for these. When click your checkbox `modelItems` changes but `filteredModelItems` does not change.I think this can be source of problem.

Comment: I believe you're correct here. I placed `filteredModelItems = modelItems;` in my `onCheckChanged()` method. However, this replaces the entire list with those that appeared in filtered. How do you think this issue could be fixed?

Comment: I think that store all data in `modelItems`, for everything else use `filteredModelItems` in. In your adapter class keep just `filteredModelItems`. Do this `filteredModelItems = modelItems;` in activity.   Before close filtering check checked items in `filteredModelItems` and set `isChecked()` and than refresh adapter to `modelItems`

Comment: I think I've got it to work using a for loop. Could you kindly verify? I'll add it to an answer below

Comment: Yes, for loop required for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Much obliged.