# CursorAdapter _id is not unique

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I think this might be a common problem with CursorAdapter but I could not find any related articles of this issue.

Basically, I am working with a CursorAdapter which populates data to a RecyclerView. When I pass a cursor with a unique _id column to the Adapter, everything works fine.

However, when I have a cursor that contains the _id column which is not unique, the adapter messes up my items. This cursor is a resultset returned by joining two tables in the SQLite Database, in case you would like to know why.

I solved this issue by setting cursorAdapter.hasStableIds(false). In fact, the adapter is then working perfectly again.

Finally, my questions:
- Did I solve the issue correctly?
- What will happen behind the scene when hasStableIds is set to false?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217416/android-what-is-the-meaning-of-stableids

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26206584/1450401

Comment: @edwin Please vote to close instead.

Comment: @CL. I was just trying to be nice , this question is already answered

Comment: @edwin That is exactly what the close-as-duplicate function is for.