# Android: How to get constant position values in expandable list view

Tags: android, position, expandablelistview

presently i'm working on expandable list view. Without using the AsynchronousTask i'm getting the constant position values (when i'm reloading the page, positions are remain same) but when i'm using the AsynchronousTask, the position values are changing (when i'm reloading the particular page). How to maintain expandable list view position values as constant when i'm reloading?

**Edit:** I am using this example https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/ExpandableListView

Not only by the AsynchronousTask, when reloading the page also i am getting different positions

My code: https://github.com/kiranlanke/ListViewDrop

Comment: Are you using stable IDs ?

Comment: Ok but please post your code so I can see what you're doing there :).

Comment: Sorry for late [here](https://github.com/kiranlanke/ListViewDrop) is my code. After importing, expand any list and see the logCat, there is a Log.e with "Expanded" tag and reload the page (Click reload button) and again expand the same list view (which is expanded earlier) then see the "Expanded"  tag in logCat. Then you will find out the different positions. Thank you

Comment: Hey , sorry for being so late . I looked at your code and noticed you don't use the technique described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217416/android-what-is-the-meaning-of-stableids  ; I think this will solve your problem. Using this you can update one item.